# Ajax loaded content in Jquery tabs not interacting in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, struts, jquery-tabs

I am facing a strange issue, im using jquery UI tabs and loading an external JSP via AJAX inside the tab.
Everything is working fine in IE 7,8,9 but when i use Firefox 16.x its rendering the content but the content action items such as buttons, hyperlinks , dropdown lists are all visible but are kind of disabled , i.e i can't click on them and perform some action.Please let me know if its a known issue or i overlooked something. PFB the JS and HTML code i used in JSP. I am using the jquery in struts 1.xx framework.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
         beforeLoad: function( event, ui )
          {   
          $("#loading-imageTab").show();
          ui.jqXHR.success(function() {             $("#loading-imageTab").hide();        });

          ui.jqXHR.error(function() { 

                    $("#loading-imageTab").hide();
                   ui.panel.html(            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. "  ); 
                          }); 
          }
    });
```

**content inside body of the JSP**

```
   <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><strong class="first">
    <a href="#tabs1" id="tab1">TAB-1</a>
    </strong></li>
<li>
<strong>
<a href="paymentInquiry.do?tabIndicator=tab"id="tab2">AJAX-TAB2</a>
</strong>
</li>

</ul>

<div id="tabs1">
<!-- some content inside -->
</div>
</div>
```